# Why Task.WhenAll throws TaskCanceledException and Task.WhenAny doesnt in the same test case

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

I run this code:

```
var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancelledTask1 = .....;//starting new long-running task that accepts cancellation.Token
var cancelledTask2 = .....;//starting new long-running task that accepts cancellation.Token

//then I request cancellation
cancellation.Cancel();
//some task gets cancelled before code below executes
try
{
    //wait for completion (some task is already in cancelled state)
    await Task.WhenAll(cancelledTask1, cancelledTask2);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    Logger.Debug("await WhenAll", e);
}
```

And I get

```
await WhenAll System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

I assume that it trows because some task is already in cancelled state. Why does `Task.WhenAll` method breaks normal flow and throws the exception in case of cancelled child tasks? What is benefit from this behavior?

Then, I try the method `Task.WhenAny`:

```
var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancelledTask3 = .....;//starting new long-running task that accepts cancellation.Token

//then I request cancellation
cancellation.Cancel();
//the task gets cancelled before code below executes
try
{
    //wait for completion (the task is already in cancelled state)
    await Task.WhenAny(cancelledTask3);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    Logger.Debug("await WhenAny", e);
}
```

and it doesn't throw exceptions.

The second question is: why `Task.WhenAny` does not throw exceptions in the same case? I expect that both methods should handle cancelled tasks the same way: either throw exceptions or not.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194914.aspx The returned task will complete when any of the supplied tasks has completed. The returned task will always end in the RanToCompletion state with its Result set to the first task to complete. *This is true even if the first task to complete ended in the Canceled or Faulted state.*

Comment: Right, this is an answer for the first question. AKA "this is by diesign". Below is also interesting opinion about the second question by Doron Yaacoby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Task.WhenAny` is designed to complete whenever one of the tasks completes, where completion includes failure. I actually find it most useful when one of the tasks might fail. For instance:

```
try
{
   await Task.WhenAny(task1,task2);
   cancellationToken.Cancel(); //cancel all tasks
   await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2); //wait for both tasks to respect the cancellation
}
catch (Exception x)
{
...
}
```

Here I only need one of the tasks to complete (hence, the `WhenAny`). In which case I would like to cancel the other tasks as well. Then I call `WhenAll` to wait for the other task to respect the cancellation request, and also propagate an exception if it occurred.

In other words, `Task.WhenAny` is designed to let you do something while other tasks are still running, and it is useful for it not to throw exceptions in order to let you do whatever you want with the other tasks. `Task.WhenAll` only completes when all the tasks complete (either successfully or not). It can throw the exception because there is nothing left for you to handle, the computation is complete.

Comment: In your example you will always (at least in 99% cases) get exception from `Task.WhenAll`, right? I guess this will happen because one of the tasks gets cancelled during `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Right. It will either be an actual exception from one of the tasks, or an OperationCancelledException, because one of the tasks completed and we cancelled the other one.

Answer (score 4):

`Task.WhenAny` returns a `Task<Task>` whereas `Task.WhenAll` returns a `Task`. The outer task completes successfully no matter the state of the first completed/canceled/faulted task. The inner task is the first canceled task. So, both the inner and outer tasks have to be awaited in order for the `OperationCanceledException` to be thrown.

For example:

```
await await Task.WhenAny(cancelledTask3);
```